# Filemaker Views based on a criteria

Tags: database, filemaker

Im building a finance database in filemaker, I have got list of all transaction on table A, the headers would be date, expense type, bank name,Payee, Amount and balance (running total). Im trying to build a view which will display transactions to a specific bank. In total I have got three banks and trying to build views for each bank. Each views should have its own transactions along with running balance.

I have tried to create a new layout for each banks and added new save condition, the problem here is, if I apply a search condition, it applies to all views. Im not sure if custom views with specific criteria are possible in Filemaker, kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to - and should not - build *anything* that only serves a specific bank.

You should have a table of Banks, where each bank has a unique record (and you can add as many banks as you like, without having to modify anything in your file's schema).

To show the transactions of a specific bank, you can use a portal to the Transactions table, placed on a layout of Banks. Or you can simply perform a find in the Transactions table.

To answer your question: Filemaker does not have "filtered" layouts. Any layout is capable of showing *any* found set of records from the associated table. And all layouts associated with the same table occurrence will show exactly the same found set.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, ill try to create unique IDs to or a field to identify a bank and will try using the portal.

Comment: Good luck. If you're just starting with Filemaker, I recommend you join of the forums dedicated to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Michael. Regarding the transactions, what is possible to to is to filter a portal by specific criteria. So for example you have a portal with Transactions for Bank A, you could add a filter to it. Something like this

```
    If(Bank="BankA";Amount>0;"")
```

Comment: That makes no sense, neither as a filtering expression nor in general.